# Insert a button on a page with random number generation

Tags: php, pages, scripts, buttons

I want to add a button on my wordpress page. When the user click on it, the text box above that button show a random number between 1-10000

I am quite new to Wordpress, I want to integrate some scripts to my Wordpress site to do this random number generation. For example I can call a php function when clicking that button. And the php code helps generate that random number and put it on the text box. but I don’t know where to begin. I googled that, but there isn’t a good reference for beginners at all

Answer (score 1):

all thing you have to do is use javaScript function

**JavaScript Example:**

```
var random_number = function(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
};
document.getElementById('button_text').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("input_box").innerHTML = random_number();
};
```

**jQuery Example:**

```
$.randomBetween(0,10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery we can written as,

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#button_text',function(){
    var minNumber = 1;
    var maxNumber = 10000;
    var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
    jQuery('#input_box').val() = randomNumber;

});
function randomNumberFromRange(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```